# Contar dados da coluna e resetar após troca do cpf

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho as seguintes colunas na tabela `eventos (nome_hosp,cpf_hosp,parametro_evento, data)`.

O que preciso fazer é, aonde o valor da coluna `parametro_evento = 1`, realize uma contagem de linhas separando por **CPF**, ou seja, por pessoas.

Por exemplo:

- Caso tenha **03** dados com o CPF(numero ficticio) igual a 1

Ele me imprimirá: CPF:1 total: 3

- Caso tenha **03** dados com `CPF=1` e **02** dados com `CPF=2`

Ele me imprimirá: `CPF: 1 total:3 CPF: 2 total: 1`

Imagem da tabela

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que vem me retornando:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu gostaria que retornasse seria, no lugar de "Joao" o BPM seria apenas 1, por que de acordo com o banco de dados ele só tem uma ocorrência com o parâmetro 1 e não 3.

Código:

```
$result_transacoes = "SELECT * FROM  eventos WHERE (timestamp_evento BETWEEN '$de' AND '$ate') GROUP BY cpf_hospede";
$resultado_trasacoes = mysqli_query($conecta, $result_transacoes);
$cont_bpm=0;
while($row_transacoes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_trasacoes)){
    if($row_transacoes['parametro_evento'] == '1') {
        $result = mysqli_query($conecta,"SELECT count(*) as total from eventos GROUP BY cpf_hospede");
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $num_bpms= $data['total'];
    }
}
```

Eu acreditava que, caso fizesse um `group by` isso resolveria meu problema, porém não.

Comment: Em seu primeiro SELECT você não informou a função de agregação. Em seu segundo SELECT você a função de agregação e a cláusula GROUP BY mas não lista o campo pelo qual está fazendo a agregação. Dessa forma não tenho ideia de como você une as informações dos dois SELECT.

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor? Eu fiz o GROUP BY no 1° e 2° select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi o seu problema é mais na questão de montar o SQL.

Criei um exemplo [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b8343/4), onde você pode testar a solução

**Exemplo**

Vamos imaginar a seguinte estrutura da sua tabela

```
create table eventos(
  id integer,
  nome varchar(50),
  cpf varchar(50),
  parametro integer);
```

Com os seguintes registros

```
 insert into eventos values (1, 'Joao', '123', 1);
 insert into eventos values (2, 'Joao', '123', 1);
 insert into eventos values (3, 'Joao', '123', 1);
 insert into eventos values (3, 'Joao', '123', 0);
 insert into eventos values (4, 'Maria', '321', 1);
 insert into eventos values (5, 'Maria', '321', 1);
 insert into eventos values (6, 'Matheus', '222', 1);
```

Agora para trazermos os dados que deseja, podemos fazer tudo em um único SQL, da seguinte forma

```
select nome
      ,cpf
      ,count(if(parametro = 1, 1, null)) as TOTAL
  from eventos
 group by cpf
```

Dessa forma você conseguiria ter o resultado que deseja com um único SQL, basta adequar a sua programação PHP agora.

**Explicação**

`count(if(parametro = 1, 1, null)) as TOTAL` essa parte, irá contar todos os registros que tiverem o `parametro` igual a 1, ignorando o que for diferente de 1 setando `null` para que a função não contabilize o mesmo.

**EDITADO**

Não possuo muito conhecimento com PHP e o que sei é voltado com utilização de PDO, mas esse exemplo pode te dar uma luz de como aplicar para o seu caso:

```
$result_transacoes   = "SELECT nome_hospede, cpf_hospede, count(if(parametro_evento = 1, 1, null)) as bpm FROM eventos WHERE (timestamp_evento BETWEEN '$de' AND '$ate') GROUP BY cpf_hospede";
$resultado_trasacoes = mysqli_query($conecta, $result_transacoes);

$total_bpm=0;
while($row_transacoes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_trasacoes)){
    $nome= $row_transacoes['nome_hospede'];
    $cpf= $row_transacoes['cpf_hospede'];
    $num_bpms= $row_transacoes['bpm'];

    $total_bpm+=$num_bpms;
}
```

Cada volta que o loop der, as variáveis serão implementadas com o valor referente a linha atual da sua query. A variável `$total_bpm` será acrescida com o valor de BPM de cada linha para assim te retornar o total de BPMs referente a todos os registros retornados.

Comment: Matheus, no caso, o valor do parâmetro varia de 1-6, o código seria o mesmo? está me retornando o seguinte erro.:Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\swc\testapdf.php on line 49
Linha 48`$result = mysqli_query($conecta,"select nome_hospede,cpf_hospede,count(if(parametro = 1, 1, null)) as total from eventos group by cpf_hospede");
        `Linha 49:`$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`

Comment: @JoãoVitor verifique a seção **EDITADO** da minha resposta, coloquei um complemento que pode te ajudar.